# How do I calculate a time based on a given difference using timelocal and localtime?

Tags: perl

I'm currently building a module that deals with a lot of time related functions. I'm using localtime(time) a lot as the array (sec,min,hour,dayofmonth,mon,year,weekday,yearday,isDST) it returns is useful for timestamping, and would like to use this wherever possible for consistency.

I need to create a way of working out a time based on a given time difference (i.e. 'what was the date 5 days ago?' sort of thing). My current thinking would be to set up the difference either as a 'difference array' (so something like [0,0,0,-5,0,0,0,-5,0] for the example) and adding this to the basetime to give a new date. But this has problems with boundary times (e.g. rolling back to the previous month) and keeping everything alligned correctly (e.g. daylight savings).

My other line of thought would be to convert this back to the time value using timelocal(), giving a flat difference and adding it to the base time to get the resultant time, then converting back using localtime to bring it back in line with the rest of the module. But this may be problematic as it may handle the potentially negative values erratically.

Of course I could normalise the array values for the first method, or have a series of values to subtract from the time value (so a list of constants, Day = 8400, hour = 3600, min = 60 sort of thing). But both of these are fiddly and my question is essentially is there a different (& more elegant) approach I could take to solve this and still be able to get the time back into an array used by localtime so it's consistent with the rest of the module?

Comment: You might want to use DateTime module and DateTime::Duration http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.01/lib/DateTime/Duration.pm

Comment: `timelocal` cannot be used for date arithmetic. Providing out of range values sometimes gives incorrect results.

Comment: Not all days have 86400 seconds, so no, you couldn't use a constant like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'local' );
$dt->subtract( days => 5 );
say $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

`$dt->epoch` returns a value `localtime` accepts.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way to do it is to use time-based objects. They allow you to do the calculations at a higher, more abstract level, which will save you from all the conversions between `localtime` and `timelocal` and dealing with day/month/year boundaries.

There are various modules that allow you to do it. I recommend that you start with [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) (part of the core, and also very fast and lightweight) and move to something heavier if that's not sufficient for your needs.

```
use Time::Piece;    # takes over localtime()
use Time::Seconds;  # use constant ONE_DAY

my $now = localtime();
my $five_days_ago = $now - ONE_DAY * 5;

print $now, "\n";           # same as if you used localtime() w/o Time::Piece
print $now->datetime, "\n"; # 2000-02-29T12:34:56 (ISO 8601)

my $diff = $now - $five_days_ago;
print $diff->pretty, "\n";
```

`Time::Piece` overrides `localtime` in a backwards-compatible way, so you should be able to introduce it painlessly to your existing code.

Comment: That will occasionally give the wrong answer. Not all days have `ONE_DAY` seconds.

Comment: Date/time math can be incredibly complicated if you have to account for time zones, daylight savings time, leap seconds, etc.  The `DateTime` is the gold standard for handling this class of problem.

Comment: Be that as it may, this code satisfies what the original question was asking. I did also say that you can use something heavier if it is not sufficient.